# Calender not recorded in the codedUi Automation testing visual studio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am working on codedUI automation testing. But i am facing challange, how to record the process for the calender and made custom logic with sqlserver.If i use the Clt+shft+r for the calender recording then i am not getting the calender values in the Recorded process.
If i use copy and Paste technique the value of calender in the textBox then i am getting error:- Cannot perform 'SetProperty of Text with value "04/02/2013" on the control.

Please help me.It's very Urgent, I shall be highly thankful,

Thanks and Regards,
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting "04022013", ie without the "/" characters. Some web pages generate the "/" characters as text is entered into a date box.

Comment: I tried to "04022013" without "/" Chracters but getting same error:-"Cannot perform 'SetProperty of Text with value \"04022013\"' on the control. Additional Details: \r\nTechnologyName:  'Web'\r\nControlType:  'Edit'\r\nId:  'txtCaregiverPayRateEffectFrom'\r\nName:  'ctl00$MainContent$ctl01$txtCaregiverPayRateEffectFrom'\r\nTagName:  'INPUT'\r\n"

Comment: Hi,If anybody has the appropriate answer, then please share as i'm in a great trouble.

Comment: We need more details of the application being tested. Is it WPF, MFC, WFA, etc? Where does the calendar control come from, is it a standard Windows control or from a third party library or your own custom control? What does the phrase "_made custom logic with sqlserver_" in the original question mean? How does the calendar interact with the user and why do you want to record a hover action with the Control+Shift+R?

Comment: it's asp.net website.In this developers used jqury calender.User select the date and date automatically fill in the ReadOnly textBox.we need fetch the values(date) of calender in the readOnly text box for  when process being recorded. we didn't get the readonly text box with calender date.So,how we will change these datetime in the readOnly textbox during dynamically change,when we run the CodedUitest.
If still you need more information,then please let me know.

Comment: Mathew Aniyan's blog on MSDN discusses jquery and it explicitly mentions how he handled a calendar data picker. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2011/10/21/coded-ui-tests-for-jqueryui.aspx

Comment: I had already tried solution in this link.But not get success.

Comment: Hi, I am not getting How we will make readonly textBox to the writable in codedUi automation testing vs 2012 Ultimate.Due to this reason, I am unable to record the datetime during recording process.it's asp.net website,In this developers used jqury calender.So please help me Urgent.If anybody know the solution.